# Does tomcat7 supports jdk11?

Tags: tomcat7, java-11

I am trying to upgrade jdk8 in one of my applications to java11 and I am using tomcat7. Does tomcat 7 supports jdk11 or do I need to use tomcat9?

Comment: Read about the requirements of tomcat at the pages of apache.

Answer (score 0):

See there http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.htm, Tomcat 7 supports JDK 1.6 and later